# Given a relation with FDs, compute the closure of set of attributes

Tags: database, relational-database, functional-dependencies

> Consider the relation schema `R = ABCDG` with following *functional dependencies* (FD)
>
> ```
> AB  -> C
> C   -> A
> BC  -> D
> ACD -> D
> D   -> EG
> BE  -> C
> CG  -> BD
> CE  -> AG
> ```
>
> Compute closure of `BD` and `CA`.

How we can find them?

Answer (score 2):

The *closure* of a set of functional dependencies, *F*, means all the functional dependencies logically implied by *F*. For example, given

- `BC -> D`, and
- `D  -> EG`

we can apply [Armstrong's axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms) to derive

- `D  -> E`,
- `D  -> G`,
- `BC -> E`,
- `BC -> G`,

and so on.

When you've derived every FD implied by *F*, you have the *closure* of *F* with respect to R. In your case, you want to derive every FD logically implied by BD and CA.

As far as I know, every textbook on relational database theory includes one or more algorithms to compute the closure of a set of functional dependencies.  Your best bet is to follow one of the algorithms in your textbook, if you have one.

Comment: You're showing how to find the closure of a particular set of functional dependencies, but it would be nice if you focus on the problem of the OP, i.e. you should have answered to the particular case/problem of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple algorithm for computing the closure of a set of attributes X:

> ```
> Closure(X, F)
> 1  INITIALIZE V:= X
> 2  WHILE there is a Y -> Z in F such that:
>    - Y is contained in V and
>    - Z is not contained in V
> 3       DO add Z to V
> 4  RETURN V
> ```